# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable, webscrapin Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-3.5

This code is to search a movie from a webpage and print the first title of the search result.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pprint

def infopelicula(nombrepelicula):
    my_url='http://www.imdb.com/find?ref_=nv_sr_fn&q='+nombrepelicula+'&s=tt'
    rprincipal = requests.get(my_url)
    soup= BeautifulSoup(rprincipal.content, 'html.parser')
    title = soup.findAll("td", class_="result_text")
    for name in title:
        titulo = name.parent.find("a", href=True)
        print (name.text)[0]
```

It does work but when print the title, the Error appears.
Here an example:

```
>>>infopelicula("Harry Potter Chamber")
Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets (2002) 
Traceback (most recent call last):File "<pyshell#49>", line 1, in <module>
infopelicula("Harry Potter Chamber")
File "xxxx", line 14, in infopelicula print (name.text)[0]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this one:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def infopelicula():
    my_url = 'http://www.imdb.com/find?ref_=nv_sr_fn&q="Harry Potter Chamber"&s=tt'
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(my_url).text, 'lxml')
    for name in soup.find_all("td",class_="result_text"):
        title = name.find_all("a",text=True)[0]
        print (title.text)
infopelicula()
```

Partial output:

```
Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone
Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire
Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince
Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows: Part 2
```

For the first title only:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def infopelicula():
    my_url = 'http://www.imdb.com/find?ref_=nv_sr_fn&q="Harry Potter Chamber"&s=tt'
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(my_url).text, 'lxml')
    for name in soup.find_all("td",class_="result_text")[:1]:
        title = name.find_all("a",text=True)[0]
        print (title.text)
infopelicula()
```

Output:

```
Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets
```

Answer (score 2):

In Python3.5, `print` is a function that returns `None`, which (as the error clearly says) can't be subscripted.

Maybe you meant `print(name.text[0])`?

Comment: I think `name.text` makes more sense. `name.text[0]` would print the 1st letter of the name.

Comment: I did both, print(name.text[0]) prints me nothing and name.text prints me all the titles and I just one the first

Comment: Now I used name.text[1] and it prints the first letter of each title :/

Comment: What is your expected output? Is it the title only?